# Magento 2, make new order status visible on frontend for customer account

Tags: customer-account, order-status

I have created a new *order status* **refunded** from `admin->settings->order status`, it is possible to have this order status visible for customer account, so when I make a credit memo for an order, then customer can see this **Refunded** status, instead of "*Closed*" , in their order list on frontend?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creating a new order status, you have to assign it, for doing this go to stores->order status-> in the grid click on "**Assign Order Status to State**".**Please see the screenshot for more ref**.

[image]

[image]

Essentially how the order status for closed works is :

1. After an order is placed, it should be invoiced, shipped, and refunded fully means the amount the customer has paid including the shipping charges and taxes, after that you will find the options dropdown as "Refunded".**Please check this screenshot**.

[image]

In the front, the customer viewing area also, the "Refunded" order status will show. **Please check this screenshot**.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign status (Refunded) to state (Closed) and check the **Visible On Storefront** checkbox.
[image]

Click on **Save Status Assignment** button.Now you can see the result.

[image]

Thanks.